# javax validation api not working for pojo validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok, spring-annotations

I have a POJO class where the class variables are getting injected by `@Value` annotation. I am trying to validate my class variables using javax validation api & so I have tried `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty` and `@NotBlank`, but all of them seem not to be validating or throwing any kind of exception even when a blank/null value is present in the application.yml file. Any idea as to how can I validate my POJO here using the javax validation api?
PS: I am using lombok to generate my getter/setter.

Below is my sample code!

**POJO Class:**

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class Credentials {

    @NotBlank
    @Value("${app.username}")
    private String user_name;

    @NotBlank
    @Value("${app.password}")
    private String password;

}
```

Below is the application.yml file:

```
app:
    username: '#{null}'
    password: passWord
```

Even if I provide a blank value, I don't get any exception when I try to print these values in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095813/4506703) can be applied.

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Credentials {

    private final String user_name;

    private final String password;

}
```

```
@Configuration
@Validated
public class CredentialsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Credentials credentials(
        @NotBlank @Value("${app.username}") final String user_name,
        @NotBlank @Value("${app.password}") final String password) {

        return new Credentials(user_name, password);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation will only work for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes combined with using `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

The reason you don't get any exception is that `@Value` only looks for presence of the attribute in the properties, it doesn't care what the value of that attribute is, unless you are assigning a mis-matching datatype value.